# ParseUser Query Android - Store users in List

Tags: java, android, parsing

I have a parse query that retrieves users stored in Parse if their xyz field is true. I have tested that the query does do this correctly in an activity, by passing the data via an intent to another activity within the done() call. However, I'd like to call the parse query via a fragment and store the list of users in that fragment to be used later, in mDataset.

*Fragment*

`protected List mDataset;`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
    query.whereEqualTo("xyz", true).findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for (ParseObject user : objects) {
                    String eachUser = user.getObjectId();
                    mDataset.add(eachUser);    
                    // here i would pass mDataset via intent if I was using two activities (which I'd rather not do)
                }
            } else {
                // handle Parse Exception here
            }
        }
    });
```

Instead, mDataset remains empty after the done() call completes. How do I go about fixing this? Thanks.

Comment: The first thing to do is check that you receive the `objects` result and that the exception is null

Comment: @inmyth I can verify that the objects are received